# Docker in window map between windows folder and linux folder

Tags: windows, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

Am I able to map docker Linux container to windows folder?

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v c:/docker/volumes/nginx/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro --network nginx-proxy-network --ip 172.18.0.3 jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

Comment: Do you want to map docker socket?

Comment: I want to map a folder in Linux to a Windows folder via docker volumes